# OpenCL GL interop, invalid memobject (error -38)

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl

I'm trying to establish a shared GL-texture and CL-image in order to draw the results of a ray tracing kernel. My code for the shared setup is

```
// Check if supported
CLManager& manager = CLManager::instance();
if (!manager.supportsGLInterop())
{
    std::cout << "Error: OpenCL-OpenGL interop not supported on this platform\n";
    exit(-1);
}

// Create shared context
CGLContextObj cglContext = CGLGetCurrentContext();
CGLShareGroupObj cglShareGroup = CGLGetShareGroup(cglContext);

cl_context_properties props[] =
{
    CL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY_USE_CGL_SHAREGROUP_APPLE,
    (cl_context_properties)cglShareGroup, 0
};

cl_int err;
cl_context sharedContext = clCreateContext(props, 0, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &err);
if (!sharedContext)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to create shared context\n";
    exit(-1);
}

// Create OpenGL texture
GLuint texture_handle;
glGenTextures(1, &texture_handle);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_handle);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_LINEAR        );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER , GL_LINEAR        );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S     , GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T     , GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

cl_mem cl_image = clCreateFromGLTexture(sharedContext, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, texture_handle, &err);

if (!cl_image || err != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to create shared texture!\n";
    exit(-1);
}

manager.setKernelArg(7, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&cl_image);
```

where manager is just a utility class for holding the current CL-context and kernels etc. The code for setKernelArg is

```
void CLManager::setKernelArg(int n, size_t size, void* data)
{
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, n, size, data);
    if (status != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "Set kernel arg failed with error code " << status << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    std::cout << "Successfully set kernel argument " << n << "\n";
}
```

When I try to run this, I get no error-messages until I try to actually set the kernel argument, then it fails with error -38, invalid mem object. As far as I know, my setup is in the correct order (first starting OpenGL, then OpenCL, then creating the GL-texture, then creating the CL-image). I'm at a loss right now as to what could be wrong with the resulting image, since none of the errors that could have happened during creation actually do.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain, but looking at this:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_gl_sharing.html

The only pixel-format required to be supported by both GL and CL is RGBA. It is of course allowed for a driver to support other pixel-formats too... But not required by the specification.

I'm not saying this IS the problem, but I know from personal experience that sharing images between CL and GL is a bit tricky, and pixel formats, channel order, internal ordering, driver versions and lots of other things can be a factor as to whether your image can be shared or not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that's good to know! Unfortunately, I tried it and the result is still the same